# Distinguish {k: :v} vs. [:k, :v] when iterating through Hash/Array

Tags: ruby

I need to implement the callback on `#each`. The receiver of `each` might be both `Array` and `Hash`. So, I have a code like:

```
receiver.each do |k, v|
  case receiver
  when Hash then puts "#{k} = #{v}"
  when Array then puts "[#{k}, #{v}]"
  end
end
```

The check for receiver is lame, though. Is there a way to receive/interprete a codeblock argument[s] to clearly distinguish the following cases:

```
{ a: 1, b: 2 }
```

versus

```
[[:a, 1], [:b, 2]]
```

I tried parenthesis, single argument, splatted argument. Everything just gets an `Array` of size `2`. Am I doomed to stick with explicit type check?

Comment: `puts receiver.inspect`

Comment: You can check the type of `receiver` before entering the loop to make it more efficient. Not sure what you mean by it being lame. I don't think there's anything about `k` and `v` that will tell what type of collection they came from.

Comment: Why do you need to check the receiver type within the block instead of outside it? Do note that you can override `each` for the source `Array` and `Hash` objects respectively.

Comment: I don't understand. If the receiver is an array, for example, `Array#each` is invoked, so there's no need to check the class of the receiver. Also, you certainly wouldn't want to redefine `Array#each` like that. Please clarify.

Comment: This almost sounds like an XY problem. Perhaps explaining why you want to know and supply code that'd wrap the `each` block would help us understand. `Hash.each` is going to hand your block key/value pairs as array elements, so inside the block you're stuck. But we shouldn't care whether something comes from an array or a hash.

Comment: @theTinMan I need to recursively iterate through the complex structure, say a hash, containing other hashes and arrays (and actually everything responding to `#each`.) I am writing a `Module` to be included into any class to make it “embeddable.” This class itself might delegate deep iteration to it’s nested arrays/hashes. This `Module` provides a method `to_my_hash`. Actually, you’ve answered my question with “inside block you are stuck,” thanks. I have nothing against checking the type explicitly, just wondered whether this information might be gathered from the block arguments.

Comment: Remember the concept of "[Duck Typing](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Duck_typing)" is that we don't care where or what things are, if they respond to the methods we need. It looks, smells, and "quacks" like an array, so it's an array. Where it came from is immaterial. Wanting to know whether it came from an array or a hash really smells like you're wandering down the wrong path.

Comment: And, I'm not sure why someone gave a down vote, since you asked the question well, even if it's possibly not the right way to do something. Here's a +1 to maintain the harmony in the universe.

Comment: @theTinMan I am aware of duck typing. Let’s be more precise: I need to build a graph and `[:a, :b]` are two leafs, while `{a: :b}` is the only one. That’s it.

Comment: Ah. Then that makes sense. And, from the comments you see where you can sniff whether it's an array or a hash.

Comment: Why don't you monkey patch `to_whatever_format_this_is` methods into various places? Similar to how `to_json` is implemented.

Comment: @muistooshort I did. I wondered about a particular problem: may I know from inside a block that values were provided by a hash. Kinda parenthesis trick like `((k, v))`, or whatever.

Answer (score 1):

The best you can do is to get the type check out of the loop:

```
def foo(receiver)
  format = receiver.is_a?(Array) ? "[%s, %s]" : "%s = %s"
  receiver.each do |k_v|
    puts format % k_v
  end
end
```

- See [String#%](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.2.2/String.html#method-i-25)

---

If you want to tell, within the *each* block, whether the key/value pair came from an array or a hash, you have to resort to monkey patching.  It can be done, but it's pretty awful:

```
class Hash
  orig_each = instance_method(:each)
  define_method(:each) do |&block|   
    orig_each.bind(self).call do |kv|
      def kv.from_hash?
        true
      end
      def kv.from_array?
        false
      end
      block.call(kv)
    end
  end
end

class Array
  orig_each = instance_method(:each)
  define_method(:each) do |&block|   
    orig_each.bind(self).call do |kv|
      def kv.from_hash?
        false
      end
      def kv.from_array?
        true
      end
      block.call(kv)
    end
  end
end
```

in use:

```
e = {a: 1, b: 2}
e.each do |kv|
  p [kv.from_hash?, kv.from_array?, kv]
end
# => [true, false, [:a, 1]]
# => [true, false, [:b, 2]]

e = [[:a, 1], [:b, 2]]
e.each do |kv|
  p [kv.from_hash?, kv.from_array?, kv]
end
# => [false, true, [:a, 1]]
# => [false, true, [:b, 2]]
```

Comment: Yes, I am aware of checking for the receiver outside of the loop, thanks. The snippet in the question was oversimplified, the goal was _to distinguish them from inside the loop_, that’s why I put in inside. In real life there would be not just string formatting.

Comment: @mudasobwa I've added a bad idea to my answer.

Comment: I have thought about that and for the sake of my particular problem it’s even simpler: I just need to patch `Hash#each` only. Anyway, thanks.